# How can I bypass modules in apache?

Tags: apache, apache2

I have an apache server running on an embedded device that serves webpages to clients using a bunch of custom modules.

I'm now trying to load some webpages from the device using htttp://127.0.0.1/blah.html

These pages don't need any of the custom modules since they don't use any of their processing.

The problem is apache still runs through all the modules when loading the page and this causes the page to load very slowly even though it's coming from the local filesystem.
I've tried using file: to retrieve the pages but then some pages don't display correctly because we are using jquery.

All the pages that don't need the modules are in a specific directory but not in the 'ServerRoot' or 'DocumentRoot'

I've tried putting checks in all the modules to disable the processing but it's still isn't good enough because it still runs through the modules.

Is there a way for me to add another module that makes a check and then stops all the rest from running?

Other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Answer found: Someone on the apache forum suggesting running a seperate instance of apache on a different port and only loading the modules needed.  I've tried that approach and it gets me the behavior I want.  Just wanted to update with an answer if anyone else is having the same issue.

Comment: Good solution.  I'd run the one with all the modules on a different port.  You can tie the two together using mod_proxy if you want.  Run mod_proxy on the simple apache on port 80 and use it to fetch from the other apache instance so that you don't expose multiple ports.